# Encryption & Decryption Question

Tags: java, encryption

Greetings all
i want to know how to make good encryption and decryption for something in java 
and is is possible for anyone to decrypt something encrypted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always possible.  Encryption/decryption is only as good as the underlying algorithm.  Given enough time and computing power, anything can be done.

Try http://www.jasypt.org/

Comment: Actually I believe a one-time pad (whereby the key is the same length as the message) is considered unbreakable (albeit not very practical).

Comment: One-time pad encryption, if done correctly, is literally impossible to crack, though as Adamski suggests it is very difficult to perform in practice.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited to be more technically correct**

> ... is possible for anyone to decrypt something encrypted ?

The encryption algorithm will dictate how long it will take for someone to decrypt your encrypted data, like duffymo said.

[WEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy) for wireless routers would be a good example of an security algorithm that does not take much time to break.  The underlying encryption algorithm (RC4) is easily exploitable due to it used in the wrong context.  RC4 is not broken, the designers used RC4 for the wrong application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws

If you use an encryption algorithm in the wrong context, then you may be building false sense of security.

Comment: For the record, WEP isn't an encryption algorithm, it's a security algorithm that uses an underlying encryption cipher (RC4). In that particular case, the weakness of the protocol isn't due to the algorithm (RC4) being faulty, but instead to other weaknesses of the approach.

Comment: @Ian Varley Ah, you are correct about RC4 being the actual underlying algorithm.  Like you said, WEP was unfortunately used in the wrong application.

Answer (score 3):

Cryptography is a big subject with a long history, but the basic idea is that you're using a "secret" to prevent someone else from seeing something (data, a message, etc). There are many ways to hide information, but the best ones are based on time-tested, mathematically sound algorithms. For that reason, it's uncommon for a layperson (i.e. not a mathematician or advanced computer science guru) to write a successful encryption algorithm from scratch. Instead, most people use one of the existing set of algorithms, some of which (like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)) are international standards. These combine a publicly-known "scrambling" algorithm with a small "secret" key that only you (or a small group) know; without the key, you can't get the data.

There are cases where "brute force" can be used to get the data--for example, trying every possible key. This, of course, takes time and computing power, and for a sufficiently large key size, is effectively impossible (i.e. there are more possible keys than the number of atoms in the universe).

So, if you use a well known, well tested algorithm, with a large key, you can be pretty assured that your data can't be gotten by force.

(Of course, there are other ways to skin a cat--like calling you pretending to be someone who should know the key, and getting you to tell them ...)

There are java libraries for every major encryption algorithm that you can simply include in your project and use (as @duffymo said, http://www.jasypt.org/ is a good place to start).

Answer (score 0):

The latest editions of AES should be perfectly fine for all *practical* purposes, but are not *theoretically* unbreakable.

You can use AES right out of the box with the latest versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cipher tool for do your encryption and decryption.
1. First you should need to import cipher for your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-cipher</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you Are using gradle

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.plexus/plexus-cipher
compile group: 'org.sonatype.plexus', name: 'plexus-cipher', version: '1.1'
```

Then you can try with those.

```
public static String encrypt(String strClearText,String strKey) throws Exception{
    String strData="";

    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
        byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
        strData=new String(encrypted);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    return strData;
}
```

Here is the decrypt method. This takes the encrypted text and the same key as the input.

public static String decrypt(String strEncrypted,String strKey) throws Exception{
    String strData="";

```
try {
    SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
    byte[] decrypted=cipher.doFinal(strEncrypted.getBytes());
    strData=new String(decrypted);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new Exception(e);
}
return strData;
```

}